# Lambda binary payload encoding in Go

Tags: http, go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to write a lambda that will return a .WAV file in chunks over HTTP.  I've got my actual data in a byte slice (`outputPayload [] byte`) and am trying to pass it back.  While the request seems to run, the response received is of a different length to what I expect and seems to be corrupted.  Here's my code:

```
//Create the necessary headers
responseHeader := make(map[string]string)
responseHeader["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes"
responseHeader["Content-Range"] = fmt.Sprintf("%s/%d", rangeRequired, fileSize)
responseHeader["Content-Type"] = fileType // this will be "audio/wav"
responseHeader["Content-Length"] = fmt.Sprintf("%d", returnedByteCount)

responseBody := string(outputPayload)
return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
    StatusCode: http.StatusPartialContent,
    Headers:    responseHeader,
    Body:       responseBody,
}, nil
```

As a basic check, using `more` at the command line, the start of the original file looks like this:

```
RIFF$^?^C^@WAVEfmt ^P^@^@^@^A^@^B^@D<AC>^@^@^P<B1>^B^@^D^@^P^@data^@^?^C^@ESC^@^Y^@
```

While the downloaded file looks like this:

```
RIFF$^?^C^@WAVEfmt ^P^@^@^@^A^@^B^@D�^@^@^P�^B^@^D^@^P^@data^@^?^C^@ESC^@^Y^@
```

I'm guessing I have an encoding issue somewhere.  My hunch is the string conversion is the problem, but that's the variable type I need for an APIGatewayProxyResponse "Body" component. How do I change my code output to ensure the payload matches the original file?

Comment: Have you gotten this to work locally?

Comment: @DanielFarrell Not tried that, but I see where you're going - maybe isolate the problem as either the function or something going on in API Gateway?  Will see if I can build a local version.